# Angular RXJS Long Poll

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, long-polling, behaviorsubject

I have a backend that maintains a store for the frontend. with every hit I am returning the full store that includes an array of messages that should be rendered.

Fetching data from backend is via long poll implemented in a service.

The problem is: DOM not keep updating with every cll to the backend, I am trying to render the update only not the full array.

with the current implantation POM updates with every hit.
Is there a way to solve it ??

I tried the following code:

In my html template:

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages$ | async">
{{message}}
</div>
```

in the components ts file:

```
messages$ = storeService.messages;
ngOnInit(){
this.messages$.subscribe();
}
```

in Store Service:

```
  get messages(): Observable<any> {
    return this._messages.asObservable();
  }
 
  private _messages = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
 
  messages$ = this._messages.asObservable()

 storeGet$ = this.http.get(EndPoint)
getStore(){
return timer(0, 15000).pipe(
        concatMap(() => storeGet$),
        map(resp => {
 
          this._messages.next(resp['messages'])
        })
      )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is

```
messages$ = timer(0, 15000).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => this.http.get(EndPoint)),
  map(resp => resp['messages'])
)
```

Comment: I need to keep this poll in the service as many other components will use it.

Comment: That is what you put in the service, maybe add a shareReplay() at the end of the stream if multiple components need the latest pool results.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on the `ngFor` `let` variable.
The "ngFor" should look something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages$ | async">
    {{message}}
</div>
```